# Move x and y coordinates of object on selection

Tags: objective-c

Is it **possible** on selection of an object in this case the search bar, move it up to the top of the application view? How would I do that?

Currently the search bar is in the middle of the screen and when you press/click on it the table view appears under it.

Normally, when you press/click the search bar the navigation bar disappears and the search bar moves up. But because I have moved the search bar into the middle of the application and hid the navigation bar it no longer jumps to the top on selection.

Comment: What Operating System?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `UIView animateWithDurations`.

So you'd have some code along the lines of:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
       [yourSearchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(newX, newY, yourSearchBar.frame.size.width,
        yourSearchBar.frame.size.height)];
}
completion:^(BOOL finished) {}
];
```

That'll animate the move to a new X and Y coordinate so you can set where you want the bar to. Have that in a function that's triggered when the `UISearchBar` receives a touch event.

Comment: How would I create function to detect a touch event on UISearchBar? And thanks.

Comment: Try `[yourSearchBar addTarget: action: forControlEvents:]` when you initialise the view. That'll just add a new target to be notified when the event occurs.

Comment: How would I add that to the above code? I'm new too objective c. :)

Comment: So in your view controller where you have the search bar, add the method `viewWillAppear`, call `[super viewWillAppear]` then add that `addTarget` method after. If that's still a bit unclear I'll write a quick gist with it in.

Comment: That quick gist would help a lot! :)

Comment: the newX and newY do I replace those with numbers?

Comment: Yeah, replace the `newX` and `newY` with the coordinates you want to move the search bar to. Here's a gist on the `viewWillAppear` method: https://gist.github.com/nicholassmith/6077829